OpenLDAP - BindDN using "o=" for domain name
Usually to query OpenLDAP server I'm using following query
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://host -b dc=domain,dc=com uidNumber=4158

But recently I saw the other way to query
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://host -b o=domain.com uidNumber=4158

What is that "o=" format , and how should I configure my LDAP server to use it ?
Thanks!

"O" in this context is the "organization" attribute. OpenLDAP probably has a configuration for relative DNs so you can specify a format "cn=jsmith,o=acmecorp,c=us" or something similar.


What is that "o=" format

It's the original OSI X.500 Directory format that very much predates dc=. The original structure of the Directory was supposed to look like this:
[root]                                        |  rootDSE
    C=US                                      |    country
        O=University of Michigan              |      organization
    C=NL                                      |    country
        O=SURFnet                             |      organization
            OU=Network Information Center     |        organizationalUnit

...with each country's subtree delegated to some kind of national directory servers. The naming format was not DNS-based because X.500 itself was meant to become the "DNS" of the OSI network, with the entire OSI protocol suite being a direct competitor to Internet protocols.
In other words, the O attribute identifies a company or other organization name, not a domain name. (Though nothing stops you from putting a domain name there, but that's not really what it's meant for.)
Today it's rarely used in LDAP due to Active Directory's influence (making everyone think dc is the only way), but you can still see [blah], O=Foo, C=US on TLS certificates – and even more so on S/MIME certificates – as their X.509 format was directly part of the X.500 directory system that LDAP descends from.

how should I configure my LDAP server to use it ?

There is no special configuration for OpenLDAP to use this format (aside from having this attribute in schema) – you literally specify o=Widgets Inc. as your database suffix.
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
olcSuffix: o=Example

While the original examples would have a country attribute ("o=Foo,c=XX"), in LDAP that's entirely optional and you can directly use "o=Foo" as the suffix.
After defining the database, the second step usually is to populate it with at least the toplevel object (using slapadd or ldapadd). This also works as usual, except of course you need to create it as objectClass: organization instead of 'domain'.
However, this decision needs to be made at the time you create the database; changing the DB suffix afterwards generally means a dump and reload (slapcat, recreate, sed the dump, slapadd).
(It might be possible to set up a 'proxy' backend that lets you access the same DB through two different suffixes, but this would be a manual setup. There's no automatic translation from "o=a.b.c" to "dc=a,dc=b,dc=c".)

Wow @u1686_grawity! Thanks a lot for detailed answer
